# plotting degrees in IDL

Tags: plot, idl, degrees

I'm using IDL 8.2 
I have a list of positions (RA and Dec) of stars and i want to plot them on a figure, eg.

37.9 ~ 37 54' 0"

37.7 ~ 37 42' 0"

I read in the positions (degrees) in as strings and extract the degrees, minutes and seconds into separate arrays. These are then used to convert the values to decimal degrees for plotting here.
[image]

I would like to also have the alternate axis labelled with degrees. i.e.

37.9 ~ 37 54' 0"

37.6 ~ 37 42' 0"

Is there a way to do this other than using something like power point to do it?

Also is there a better way, than having the axis scaled the same, to force the plot to be a square plot using the plot procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution was posted here.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/EsbGiqZnhRw

Effectively, writing a function to perform write user defined tick marks.